# Is ngAnimate not working anymore?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I can't get a simple angular animation to work. I made a simple Plunkr to show it: https://plnkr.co/edit/bKZev3i1WhNgKhsWOZIQ

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p class="fade-fx" data-ng-repeat="text in texts">{{ text.text }}</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.fade-fx.ng-enter,
.fade-fx.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
  transition: 2s linear all;
}

.fade-fx.ng-enter,
.fade-fx.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-fx.ng-leave,
.fade-fx.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.texts = [
      {
        text: 'text1'
      },
      {
        text: 'text2'
      },
      {
        text: 'text3'
      }
    ];
  });
```

The thing is I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: ngAnimate never really worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `$timeout` to your initial array initialization. See here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZB312BKV8vAD3hYttaXZ?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.texts = [{
        text: 'text1'
      }, {
        text: 'text2'
      }, {
        text: 'text3'
    }];
  });
});
```

EDIT: On an unrelated note, it would be cleaner to switch

```
.fade-fx.ng-enter,
.fade-fx.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
  transition: 2s linear all;
}
```

to

```
.fade-fx {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
  transition: 2s linear all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **From Angular Doc**
>
> Animations
>
> .enter - when a new item is added to the list or when an item is
>   revealed after a filter
>
> .leave - when an item is removed from the list or when an item is
>   filtered out
>
> .move - when an adjacent item is filtered out causing a reorder or
>   when the item contents are reordered

You need to add a search filter to make query in list only make change in "index.html" as

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="Search">
  <p class="fade-fx" data-ng-repeat="text in texts | filter:q as results">{{ text.text }}</p>
</div>
```